# SSRS Lookupset compare with more than 1 item

Tags: reporting-services, lookup

I have 2 datasets:

Dataset 1 looks like this:

```
**Name** | **Food1**
James    | Apple
John     | Banana; Orange
Jane     | Apple; Banana; Chocolate
```

Dataset 2:

```
**Food2** | **Property**
Apple    | Fruit
Banana   | Fruit
Chocolate| Snack
Orange   | Fruit
```

So now I have a table that has dataset 2 as main dataset. Now I want the table to show me something like this:

```
**Food** | **Name**
Apple    | James; Jane
Banana   | John; Jane
Chocolate| Jane
Orange   | John
```

I've tried this:

```
Join(LookupSet(Fields!Food2.Value, Fields!Food1.Value, Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset1"), "; ")
```

but anytime "Food2.Value" wants to compare with "Food1.Value", it returns nothing. My return table with this code looks like this:

```
**Food** | **Name**
Apple    | James
Banana   |     
Chocolate| 
Orange   |
```

I've also tried this, but it doesn't work either:

```
Join(LookupSet(Fields!Food2.Value, Split(Fields!Food1.Value, ";"), Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset1"), "; ")
```

I would be very thankful for any help!

Comment: Make your Dataset1 atomic. One value for column Food1.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because this is just a simple example that represents much bigger datasets in SharePoint.